# Add a dynamic HTML table footer when printing to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table with overflow allowed, with a footer and a header that repeats when there is an overflow when I print to PDF, so the table body is splited into as many pages as needed. The problem is that on my table footer I have the page number and when the table repeats I need the number to increase by one but it doesn't. I searched everywhere and can't figure it out, can someone help me?
An example code is shown below.

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
           </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       {{#table_content}}
           <tr> 
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               ...
               <td></td>
           </tr>
       {{/table_content}}
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
       <tr>
           <td id="page-number"> HERE I NEED THE PAGE NUMBER </td>            
       </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
I already tried this:
 @media print {
        #page-number::after {
            counter-increment: page;
            content: counter(page);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a HTML template with a table inside it, the table has a footer and a header, inside the footer I need to put the page number, it works for single paged tables, but when my table overflows and is splited into two pages, the number just repeats itself and does not increment as it should do. I need to make the number increments when I have this situation, but its not incrementing.